# Samba Share Permissions

Tags: permissions, samba

I recently setup a shared network folder between my Ubuntu system and my Windows PC. I can move files from Windows into the folder and they show up in Ubuntu but I have no access to them. Before I can do anything with the files I need to change the owner. On and old computer When I put the files in the folder they automatically had all the permissions to use in Ubuntu. What do I need to change here?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to add `Everyone` credentials for the whole network folder that is shared by windows, adding at least the `list` and `read` permissions. You can add more permissions if you would like.
Doing so will inherit those permissions to every existing and future file that will be stored in the folder.

This will work for SMB and NFS shares by windows.
This solution is good for a home network or any network where you trust all members in it.

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]
[image: Step 3]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Before I can do anything with the files I need to change the owner.
> ```

Samba can do that for you if you are interested.

It sounds like you created a guest accessible share so anytime someone adds a file it ends up being owned and writeable only to "nobody". You can add a line to smb.conf that will convert nobody to you - for all new files added to the share:

You didn't specify how you created the shares: in smb.conf itself or via Nautilus > Local Network Share so you can add a line in the [global] section - like right under workgroup = WORKGROUP - replacing cpw7922 with your local ubuntu user name:

```
force user = cpw7922
```

Then restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

That will apply to all your shares.